# Is nightcore a type of anime?

Tags: anime-production

I have a friend who loves anime.
 She told me about nightcore and the characters in anime look like the characters in nightcore.

Are nightcore and anime the same thing?

Comment: Are they  the same because they look the same

Comment: I was just wondering because I am listening to nightcore right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nightcore is the name for a type of music edit, making things a bit faster and higher pitched. From what I've seen, it's mostly done on songs from anime, or japanese songs, and have anime-like imagery associated with it.

> A nightcore edit is a remix track that speeds up the pitch and time of its source material by 10-30%. The name is derived from Nightcore, a Norwegian duo who released pitch-shifted versions of trance and eurodance songs, but now more broadly refers to any sped-up music.

The wikipedia article has more on it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightcore

As for anime, it's the term used for animated shows and movies, typically referring to those created in Japan.

Comment: So they are the same pretty much

Comment: no, nightcore is music, anime is animated shows/movies

Answer (score 5):

No, nightcore is not Anime.

Nightcore is a music genre where the pitch and speed of a song is changed.
It is also sometimes known as nighstep or sped up dubstep.

The nightcore videos do often come paired with anime-related images instead of music videos, but is usually not related to the depicted anime whatshowever.